# sudo make modules_install ---> In: target '6.1.63/source': No such file or directory make: *** [Makefile:1574: __modinst_pre] Error 1

Tags: terminal, linux-kernel

I'm trying to compile linux kernel(6.1.63), but after compiling when I try Sudo make modules_install drops the following error:

ln: target '6.1.63/source': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:1574: __modinst_pre] Error 1
Any Idea on how to fix this?

I tried sudo make all to compile everything and then i tried sudo make modules, after that I tried again and it gave me the same error.

P.D: I'm new on Linux and thanks in advance for any answers (Sorry for bad english).